# How do I prevent cloth from being blown through an object?

Tags: cloth-simulation, collision, force-fields

After creating a dress and a hangar, I have given the dress cloth properties and set the collision properties for the dress and the hangar.  If I just leave everything as is, the dress hangs from the hangar.  My problem occurs when I add a wind force field to blow the dress.  The dress blows *through* the hangar.  Anyone have any clue what is happening?

Comment: Hi, welcome. I just tried to roughly reproduce a similar setup, leaving cloth defaults and I don't get such a behaviour...  it works well. The dress (just cloth, not collision) the hangar (collision) and the wind have default settings (just wind force jumps up to 1000)...  did you sudivide enough cloth? the more, the better usually (but not too high)

Comment: Thanks, I subdivided 3 times.  I don't know if I was using too much wind force or not.  I got the desired effect I was looking for by subdividing the dress straps and molding the them closer to the hangar and pinning the vertices over the top.  I also reduced my wind force from 1,000 to 5...

Comment: Try solidifying your dress with a solidify modifier cause sometimes when I use a flat plane, it ignores some of the physics used

Answer (score 1):

I add an answer to be able to post my example (as I intended yours) that seems to work, and I guess does what you wish:

[image]

As said I pretty much used default values for all, except wind force...
Of course I have an example, very simple, setup but this may give you an Idea of what's not working. Maybe you can provide a better example for us to check?

And here you have the file to experiment, hth:

[image]